# Does it make sense to point to same table twice on django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have this Tables

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Rule(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    next_page = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

# ... other fields
```

Obviously, I am no database or Django expert, the need for `next_page` and category are different The Rule table is supposed to be used to set the page that comes next after certain condition are met/performed by the user. My general question is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, no problem, provided this usage is natural.

For example, an airline with a table of `flight`s. Each `flight` would completely naturally have a `from` and a `destination` both of which are ForeignKeys to `Airport` objects.

Comment: Thought I was doing something wrong.